# WCF service method has different return value than the corresponding proxy in Client application

Tags: c#, wcf, service, proxy, client-side

I wrote WCF service library with the following method:

```
    [OperationContract]
    IEnumerable<string> GetMyMessages(char player);
```

I added the service library using Add Service Reference to the client application, but on the Client side the proxy method ha signature

```
    string[] GetMyMessages(char player);
```

So, when I try to return the value to a List reference I get the following error:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Why does this happen? How can I set the return value of the proxy method to be the same as the one in the original method?

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things going on here, I believe.

First, you're service method is returning an `IEnumerable<T>`, and I'm pretty sure that can't be serialized.  How do you serialize an interface?  There's no data to serialize.  I would suggest converting your return type to `List<string>`.

Secondly, when you add a service reference the default behavior for collections is to use `System.Array`.  You can change this by clicking on the "Advanced" button in the Add Service Reference dialog:

[image]

Then in the Service Reference Settings dialog, under Data Type you can set the Collection Type (note that there is no `Systems.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` option):

[image]

You could modify your operation contract as follows:

```
[OperationContract]
List<string> GetMyMessages(char player);
```

and change the default data type for collections (as above).  Then modify your client to expect a `List<string>` result as opposed to an `IEnumerable<string>`.

If you really need or want an `IEnumerable<T>` on the client side, you could do the following in your client code:

```
List<string> myList = myServiceClient.GetMyMessages('a');
IEnumerable<string> myEnumerable = myList;
```